# How to prevent useless kernel-modules from loading?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Our Ubuntu-servers all seem to have various *unused* kernel-modules loaded wasting RAM and, in the case of jfs for example, running a bunch of useless processes (`jfsCommit`).

I can use `rmmod` to get rid of them at runtime, but I wonder, what causes them to load in the first place.

Ideally, I'd be able to remove the module-binaries too.

Comment: Did you previously mount and unmount a JFS filesystem? That would cause the module to be loaded but not currently used.

Comment: No... Also most certainly haven't used `btrfs`, `ntfs` and the like either -- and all are loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the modules in question are built into the kernel, the only way is recompiling the kernel.

If they are separate modules, you can blacklist them.

Add

```
blacklist module_name
```

to the file

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

(needs restart)

Comment: Thanks. But what causes these to be loaded in the first place? Or is _everything_ available, that's not explicitly blacklisted loaded at boot?

Comment: The kernel loads the modules according to what is in the subdirectories of /lib/modules. But it's not advisable to delete files there, it tends to get messy.

Comment: So, _everything_ under `/lib/modules` is loaded which is not explicitly blacklisted?

Comment: Not everything. Modprobe will load the ones whose dependencies are on /lib/modules/$(uname - r)/modules.dep and the corresponding binaries are on /lib/modules/$(uname - r)/modules.dep.bin